# OpenGL White Screen

Tags: opengl

In my openGL program using freeglut the screen is completely whited out by this code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);   
    glPushMatrix();
        glVertex3f(trackRadius*cos((double)x), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*x), trackRadius*sin(x));
        glVertex3f((trackRadius+1)*cos((double)x), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*x), (trackRadius+1)*sin(x));
        glVertex3f(trackRadius*cos((double)x+(0.005)), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*(x+0.005)), trackRadius*sin(x+0.005));
        glVertex3f((trackRadius+1)*cos((double)x+0.005), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*(x+0.005)), (trackRadius+1)*sin(x+0.005));
    glPopMatrix();
glEnd();
```

The above code is used to display lines between two railroad tracks which are generated and displayed just fine when the above code is removed. A kart is also displayed fine.

I've discovered that if I remove glPushMatrix(); and glPopMatrix(); everything displays fine, but I need the matrix push/pop lines don't I?

Edit 1:
This is the full code I call to display my track in a class Track.cpp called from my main glut .cpp

```
void Track::RenderTrack() 
{
double x=-3.14;
glNewList(1, GL_COMPILE);  // create sphere display list for Object 1
glutSolidSphere(0.1,20,20); 
glEndList();

glNewList(2, GL_COMPILE);
for (x; x<3.14;x= x+.005)
{
//first track
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(trackRadius*cos((double)x),trackHeight * sin((double)trackNumberOfHills*x),trackRadius*sin((double)x));
glCallList(1);
glPopMatrix();

//Second track
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
glTranslatef((trackRadius+1)*cos(x),trackHeight * sin(trackNumberOfHills*x),(trackRadius+1)*sin(x));
glCallList(1);
glPopMatrix();


//Track Insides
glBegin(GL_QUADS);   
glPushMatrix();
glVertex3f(trackRadius*cos((double)x), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*x), trackRadius*sin(x));
glVertex3f((trackRadius+1)*cos((double)x), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*x), (trackRadius+1)*sin(x));
glVertex3f(trackRadius*cos((double)x+(0.005)), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*(x+0.005)), trackRadius*sin(x+0.005));
glVertex3f((trackRadius+1)*cos((double)x+0.005), trackHeight*sin(trackNumberOfHills*(x+0.005)), (trackRadius+1)*sin(x+0.005));
glPopMatrix();
glEnd();
}
glEndList();

glCallList(2); // call the list to draw it

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From opengl documentation:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd. The commands are glVertex, glColor, glSecondaryColor, glIndex, glNormal, glFogCoord, glTexCoord, glMultiTexCoord, glVertexAttrib, glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint, glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag. Also, it is acceptable to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute display lists that include only the preceding commands. If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.

`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` are not in this list, so your code is ignored.

You can put them outside the `glBegin` / `glEnd` block.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Tuition for this module has been weakened by staff being ill a lot, everyone thinks it's great but I personally am annoyed at the lack of educational support.
Thanks again!